# SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified (jquery in mvc 5)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, action

I have a mvc 5 project that this code works good. but i have just modified it for another project and it does not work. It does not call to the action
here is the jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url='@Url.Action("loadRoles", "Account")';
        $.post(url, function (data) {            
            //Do whatever u waht with response "Data"
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '@Url.Action("loadRoles", "Account")',

            dataType: 'text/javascript',
            data:'',
            success: function (Roles) {  // it does not process this section 

                var items = '<option value="' + "0" + '">' + "type" + '</option>';
                $.each(Roles, function (i, Role) {

                    items += '<option value="' + Role.Value + '">' + Role.Text + '</option>';

                });
                $("#ddrRoles").html(items);
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve Cities.' + ex);
            }

        });

        return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: I have tested both methods above . the post function and the ajax section, but no one did it right

Comment: Please use the [tag:asp.net-mvc-5] tag in the future; mvc5 an empty tag that should be removed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove a few cshtml razor comments (starting with @* and ending with *@) with unneeded dead code to resolve the syntax error in the title of this question. That is all in my case.